# How to write to a file using open() and printf()?

Tags: c, file-io, printf, output

I am opening a file with open(), and need to print to that file using printf with no output to the console. How do I do this? I can successfully create the file, and printf to the console, but that is not correct.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    char *name = "helloworld";
    fd = open(name, O_CREAT);

    char *hi = "Hello World";
    printf("%s\n", hi);

    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

I need the program to have no output to the console, but if I look at the file `helloworld`, it should have "Hello World" written inside. Such as:

```
prompt> ./hello
prompt> more helloworld
   Hello World
```

Comment: why not use `fprintf`?

Comment: I have to use printf

Comment: `freopen()` to stdout?

Comment: `open` is POSIX standard function, not a C standard library function. You can use [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) to open a file and then use [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and other functions from the standard library to write to the file.

Comment: what flags are you passing to open?  It can be tricky to get the correct set of flags the first time you try it.

Comment: What dbush said below will work, but in most cases, is bad practice.  If you use `fprintf`, you can then assign a file stream handle to the value of stdout on startup if you later decide to you do want output to stdout, i.e.:  `FILE * f = stdout`.  The "normal" way to write to a file with `printf` is to redirect stdout of your program when you call it, in which case your shell does something very similar to the code shown by dbush before calling `exec` or similar to start your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a trick to this.

You need to duplicate the open file descriptor to file descriptor 1, i.e. `stdout`.  Then you can use `printf`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int fd;
    char *name = "helloworld";
    fd = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (dup2(fd, 1) == -1) {
        perror("dup2 failed"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    // file descriptor 1, i.e. stdout, now points to the file
    // "helloworld" which is open for writing
    // You can now use printf which writes specifically to stdout

    char *hi = "Hello World";
    printf("%s\n", hi);

    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: You should remove the `close(fd)`:  `exit` or even just returning from `main` will cause `stdout` to be closed as if by `fclose(stdout)`, which will `fflush(stdout);`.  This step might be needed for the contents to be flushed to the file. Closing the system handle would prevent this.

Comment: @chqrlie Good call.  Edited.

Comment: @user2877117: if you haven't learned `dup2` yet, you could call `close(1);` before the `fd = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);`.  There is a good chance `fd == 1` after this and you wont need the call `dup2(fd, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

If you open a file with `open()` then you get an `int` file descriptor which you can write to with `write()`.

If you open a file with `fopen()` then you get a `FILE*` handle and can use the stdio family of functions to write to it, which includes `fprintf()` and `fputs()`.

These are two different levels of abstraction. `open()` doesn't mix well with the `printf()` family. You could get them to work together with `fdopen()`, but it's not a good idea to mix abstractions.

Comment: The assignment specifies using printf and open

Comment: @user2877117, looks like your instructor, or whoever created the assignment, is bit misguided.

Comment: That doesn't really help me, I am just at a loss for how to proceed

Comment: @user2877117: Ask your instructor for advice. He seems to be confused himself. How can he even assume you have a POSIX-compliant system available? Is Unix or Linux (OS-X?) required for that course? AFAIK Windows dropped POSIX-support some time ago.

Comment: Use `dup2` to redirect `stdout`.

Comment: @user2877117 On unix clones, you open a terminal window and type `man dup2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can close the standard out before you use printf, so that the output would be saved in the file directory you opened instead of printing to the console.

```
close(1); // close(STDOUT_FILENO);
fd = open(name, O_CREAT);

char *hi = "Hello World";
printf("%s\n", hi);

close(fd);
```

I'm assuming the printf() command can only print the output to one directory at one time and it would go to the default standard output directory if you do not close it first. If you find out a way to set the output directory to the fd without closing the STDOUT_FILENO, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `fopen` to handle this, a simpler trick is to use [variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), by which you can replace `printf` with `fprintf` in preprocessing. The `...` representing variable arguments in the macro is just like its counterpart in the declaration of functions with variable arguments. This trick works in C and C++. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define printf(...) fprintf(File, __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    FILE *File;

    File = fopen("file.txt", "w+");

    printf("Hello world!");

    fclose(File);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: variadic macro is used because the number of arguments of `printf` is a variable.